# How to verify that proguard is enabled in unity build?

Tags: unity-game-engine, proguard, android-proguard

I have a custom gradle file named mainTemplate inside Plugins/Android. minifyEnabled is set to true. I need to verify that proguard is actually enabled.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/AndroidMinification.html EditorUserBuildSettings.androidReleaseMinification = AndroidMinification.Proguard;

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer is pretty late, but I can see this is getting a decent amount of views (2k at writing), so I thought it'd be worthwhile to leave an answer here.

The way I did this was to simply **build an APK without ProGuard, and build an APK with ProGuard, and compare them in Android Studio**.

#### How to build an APK with / without ProGuard?

This is the default case in Unity, but just set the minify values to disabled.

These are accessible in the Editor via File --> Build Settings --> Player Settings.  And in the Inspector window, finding the Publishing Settings tab.

[image]

In the Example screenshot above you can see I have enabled ProGuard for release builds only, and not debug builds.  I'd recommend this so you can get actionable crash logs from your debug builds.

If you're building via a script this would involve including the following line somewhere in your build script:

```
EditorUserBuildSettings.androidReleaseMinification = AndroidMinification.None;
```

or

```
EditorUserBuildSettings.androidReleaseMinification = AndroidMinification.Proguard;
```

Once ProGuard is disabled, do a build.  And then do another build with it enabled.  (Note, if you followed my example above, to do a Debug build in Unity you should check the Development Build option in the Build Settings window, above the build button).

#### How to compare two APKs to see whether ProGuard is enabled?

The easiest way I know how to do this is via Android Studio.

Open up Android Studio, and hit the "Profile or Debug APK" button.

[image]

Once Android Studio is done importing your APK, you will get a better understanding of whether ProGuard is working or not pretty quickly.  For example, this is the comparison of project viewers.

[image]
[image]

It's clear that the latter has ProGuard enabled as the class names are obfuscated and it has less in the DEX files, [things that ProGuard does](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/introduction).